# When creating a HTML Table in an Email, how can add space above one row, but not above all of them?

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

When creating a HTML table in an Email, how can add space above one row, but not above all of them?

**Example:** I have a table that is two columns wide. Part way down the table I am inserting a 'sub header' of sorts by having one cell merge the two columns. Above this row, I want to have more space, but I don't want to apply this above all rows, like css would commonly do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Specify a `style` attribute on that row/cell with the padding you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be inline anyway, because many email clients do not read embedded styles (the code within `<style>...</style>`).

I.e., as @David said in comments,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>...
    </td>
    <td>...
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-top:30px">Sub-header
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can't use margin as Outlook desktops don't allow it.

An alternative that might suit you is a faux-table row, with a non-breaking space set at a specific height (both parameters there are necessary for cross-email-compatibility):

```
<tr>
  <td style="font-size:30px;line-height:30px;">&nbsp;
  </td>
</tr>
```